# ionic - changeDetectorRef detectChanges() modifies the model

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, model-binding, angular2-changedetection

In my page controller at some point i need to update the UI, and it appears that a call to chageDetector.detectChanges() in mandatory at that particular point.
What happens is: i'm re-assigning a string property in my model whose value changes some of my UI.
As soon as i call the detectChanges() method, that property acquires ***its old value***.
I'll only change names and values to my code, but apart from that, the following is what i'm working with:

First of all i have an enum:

```
enum TypeEnum { TypeA: 'A', TypeB: 'B' }
```

Then my controller:

```
selectType(type: TypeEnum) {  //type has value 'B'

  this.verify = true;
  this.setFieldXOnTypeChange(type);

                                          //this.model.type has value 'A'
  this.model.type = type;                 //this.model.type = 'B'
                                          //now this.model.type has value 'B'

  //other stuff is calculated
  this.scrollToBottom();
  this.onFieldYReturn(null, true, true);
  this.typeAccordionHeader.value = type;
  if (type == typeEnum.TypeB) {
    this.model.date = this.today;
  }
  this.setPageTitleForType(type);

                                        //before call > this.model.type: 'B'
  this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
                                        // after call > this.model.type: 'A'
}
```

This is a behaviour i never experienced before: i knew changeDetector purpose was to apply model changes to the component, nothing else.
Can anyone explain the behaviour and, in case, how to avoid it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say this.model.type changes - how do you know that? Is there template code binding? Can you share that? Is there any other method or code that deals with model obj as well?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I know that from 2 things: a) part of the UI displays values in use for type 'A' only; b) Chrome debugger and the watch list.
The template is pretty complex, since it's a page including a component that includes other atoms etc, and the model is shared across all the components, and atoms of the page, but that method in particular executes when a custom event is emitted, and the 'type' property is set exclusively in this piece of code, nowhere else.